# Android when adding support to 64bit :couldn't find DSO issue

Tags: android, react-native, x86-64, arm64

I just added support for 64bit by using **ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','x86','arm64-v8a'** , because google play store will not allow to upload APK without supporting 64bit. My application has some react-native code also

After conversion am getting an error

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libreactnativejni.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog_init.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libgnustl_shared.so caused by: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.teamta.mentouraviation/lib-main/libgnustl_shared.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:703)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:564)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:500)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:455)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.staticInit(ReactBridge.java:18)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap.<clinit>(NativeMap.java:19)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSCJavaScriptExecutorFactory.create(JSCJavaScriptExecutorFactory.java:21)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:917)
    at java.lang.Thread.run
```

by analyze the apk it found that **couldn't find DSO to load: libglog_init.so 
    couldn't find DSO to load: libglog.so 
    couldn't find DSO to load: libgnustl_shared.so**files are mixing in "**arm64-v8a**"

Comment: Please find this file `libgnustl_shared.so` in  `arm64-v8a` folder

Comment: @Silversky Technology  how to find this file

Comment: `app
   |
   src
      |
     main
        |
        jniLibs
            |
            armeabi-v7a
            |   your_lib_compiled_for_v7a.so

Comment: @Silversky Technology after support to 64 , libgnustl_shared.so is not found in "arm64-v8a" folder

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade your jitsi sdk to last update [Jitsi Meet SDK for Android](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/tree/master/android)